# need help on extracting a file when checksum matches

Tags: tar, checksum

I need a help on untaring a file when checksum matches.

Here is the scenario.

i have a tar file and its check sum is dfsafdafsafasfsaf232,  stored in a checksum file and need a script to match this checksum file and extract to specific folder when matches.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be as easy as something like this.

```
md5sum --status --check checksumfile.md5
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo >&2 "MD5 Failed"
   exit 1
else
  tar -xzf filename.tar.gz
fi
```

Of course if you aren't using md5sum/sha*sum, then you may need to see if your checksum tool has a check mode, that returns the results as the error level.

Comment: Hello Zored, Thanks for quick answer. yes script saved my time. Thank You,